# issue with random number guess game. Does not show if answer is correct

Tags: javascript

Why is this not working. There are no errors in console and compiler does not show anything specific. Probably something wrong with the variable check?

```js
document.getElementById("checknumber").onclick = function() {
  var numberSelected = document.getElementById("input").value;
  //alert(numberSelected)
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  //alert(number)
  if (input == number) {
    alert("got it");
  } else("noup not now");
}
```

```html
<p>Guess the number: </p>

<p><input id="input"> </p>

<p><button id="checknumber">Check !</button></p>
```

Comment: `else { console.log("noup not now"); document.getElementById("input").value="" };`

Comment: What exactly do you expect `("noup not now")` to do?

Comment: `input` is not really defined. The way you use it, it is the `input` element (because it has the id "input" aswell) and not its value. Also the `alert()` is missing in the else part.

Comment: `if (numberSelected == number) {`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: You haven't declared the `input` variable anywhere within the function. Also, as @mplungjan noted, your `else` statement should actually be `else { //dosomething }`

Answer (score 0):

The `input` variable is not defined anywhere, and I think you missed an `alert` in the `else("noup not now")` statement.

*Side note: you are confronting a String with a Number, in this case it behave as expected because of Js Coercion and the equality operator.*

```js
document.getElementById("checknumber").onclick = function() {
  var numberSelected = document.getElementById("input").value;
  //alert(numberSelected)
  var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  //alert(number)
  if (numberSelected == number) {
    alert("got it");
  } else {
    alert("noup not now");
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Guess the number: </p>

<p><input id="input"> </p>

<p><button id="checknumber">Check !</button></p>
```